# Process Exited Event filre when multiple word documents are open

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

need some fever , i have created one desktop application that opens multiple word documents.
but here i facing one problem that when second document is open the exited event of first document has fire without closing of that document.

Following is my code

```
   private void CreateNewProcessForEachDocument()
    {
        try
        {
            docProcess = new Process();

            docProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Concat(folderPath, fileName));
            docProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            docProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(docProcess_Exited);
             docProcess.Start();
            docProcess.WaitForExit();

            docProcess.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    } 


    private void docProcess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

                    var client = new ValidateClientClient();
                    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(string.Concat(folderPath, fileName));
                    bool fileSaved = client.SaveDocument(fileData, fileName, username);
                    string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(string.Concat(folderPath, fileName));
                    if (fileSaved && File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, don't Office products only register themselves one time in the Running Object Table?  Have you considered getting each Word Document as a COM object, and then dealing with it that way?  You can use the Interop libraries, PInvoke, or even get the type at runtime by getting active instances or marshalling Word.Document.

Answer (score 1):

When an existing instance of Word is open it reuses that instance. A short-lived process is launches that does nothing more but tell the existing instance to open another document. For that reason you can't reliably wait for Word to exit.

Maybe you have more luck with the Office COM object model.

Or, you can use `Process.GetProcessesByName` to get all existing Word instances.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind exit event with listener method.
Add this to your code:

```
docProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(docProcess_Exited);
```

**Update:**
If you just call CreateNewProcessForEachDocument() on button_click, than your application works like a simple single-thread application, as if you start new thread, you wait until it's finishes and than - continue.
Looks like you need this:

```
private void CreateNewProcessForEachDocument()
{
  var docProcess = new Process {StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"), EnableRaisingEvents = true};
  docProcess.Exited += docProcess_Exited;
  docProcess.Start();
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to put in it

Comment: but my problem is other
os handle only one winword process 
when we start new process for it then it shutdown the previous one